# SQLLite in Python throwing operational error on UNIQUE Key

Tags: python, sqlite

I get an operational error when running this code:

```
db.execute("CREATE TABLE tLPs (LP VARCHAR(20), Dir VARCHAR(255), Mercosur TINYINT, H0 TINYINT, H1 TINYINT, H2 TINYINT, H3 TINYINT, H4 TINYINT, H5 TINYINT, H6 TINYINT, H7 TINYINT, H8 TINYINT, keyid INT AUTO_INCREMENT, UNIQUE KEY(LP), PRIMARY KEY(keyid))");
```

The error says:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "KEY": syntax error
```

To "fix it" I change it to this:

```
db.execute("CREATE TABLE tLPs (LP VARCHAR(20), Dir VARCHAR(255), Mercosur TINYINT, H0 TINYINT, H1 TINYINT, H2 TINYINT, H3 TINYINT, H4 TINYINT, H5 TINYINT, H6 TINYINT, H7 TINYINT, H8 TINYINT, keyid INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(keyid))");
```

Which is basically removing the `UNIQUE KEY(LP)` constraint. So what am I doing wrong? I've done this type of thing before with other tables and have not had any problems. First time using sqlite and python, though....

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the keyword is AUTOINCREMENT no '_'. Not knowing SQLite by heart but you shouldn't need it since if you set a INT PRIMARY KEY then it will auto increment on its own when you add a new row. (More reading about autoincrement in SQLite [https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html])

Comment: Unique is not a key, but a constraint. You can either specify it when defining the row: `LP VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,` or add it later to the table `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tLPsLP ON tLPs(LP);` Note the `tLPsLP`is the name given to the constraint. You can chose that freely, but it must be unique (pun **not** intended) in the DB

Comment: Thanks! I changed it so that the column has the UNIQUE atribute.

Answer (score 0):

The `AUTOINCREMENT` is ignored because it only works with an [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) (the column type *must* be spelled `INTEGER`, not `INT` or other types with integer affinity).

A more idiomatic DDL would be ;

```
CREATE TABLE tLPs (
  LP TEXT,
  Dir TEXT UNIQUE,
  Mercosur INTEGER,
  H0 INTEGER,
  H1 INTEGER, 
  H2 INTEGER, 
  H3 INTEGER, 
  H4 INTEGER, 
  H5 INTEGER, 
  H6 INTEGER, 
  H7 INTEGER, 
  H8 INTEGER, 
  keyid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
)
```